# How to clear WooCommerce cart when user visit any product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Basically, I am running a membership ship with 3 levels. Bronze, silver, gold. They can join / buy the services (add to cart). However, only 1 membership level can add to cart.

Hence, I need to clear the cart whenever customer reach any product page (bronze, silver, gold product page).

After doing some research on WooCommerce docs, I found the function should be

`WC()->cart->empty_cart;`

My question is may I know which file should I add this line of code as I am new to WooCommerce, not sure which file to edit. Any advice?

Comment: Which plugin you are using for membership? and, How you determine that is bronze, silver, gold product page?

Comment: paid membership pro. I can add the membership level in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pmpro_hasMembershipLevel` function. You can find more of this function here - [Using the pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/content-controls/require-membership-function/) Function

Previously there was a bug in this function where you can only check on one level at a time but now I think it's fixed. so you can use it like below.

You can use `woocommerce_before_single_product` to clear the cart.

```
function clear_cart_on_membership_level_change() {

    // Check if the current page is a product
    if ( is_product() ) {
        
        // If the membership level is available, empty the cart
        if ( pmpro_hasMembershipLevel( array( 'bronze', 'silver', 'gold' ) ) ) {
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'clear_cart_on_membership_level_change' );
```

The code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

**UPDATE** as per OP's comment.

You can use the `template_redirect` hook. and you can compare with product ids of `1. bronze 2. silver 3. gold`

```
function clear_cart_on_product_page() {
    // Check if the current page is a product page
    if (is_product()) {
        // Get the current product ID
        $product_id = get_the_ID();

        // Check if the product is related to a 1. bronze 2. silver 3. gold
        if ($product_id === $bronze_product_id || $product_id === $silver_product_id || $product_id === $gold_product_id) {
            // Clear the cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'clear_cart_on_product_page' );
```

**UPDATE 2** as per OP's comment. `The flow should be like this user visit product page-> clear cart -> Add to cart -> checkout...`

You can use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` hooks to redirect to the checkout page after adding to cart requirest.

```
function redirect_to_checkout_after_add_to_cart($url) {
    // Check if the user is adding a product to the cart
    if (isset($_REQUEST['add-to-cart'])) {
        // Redirect to the checkout page
        return wc_get_checkout_url();
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout_after_add_to_cart');
```

**UPDATE 3** as per OP's comment. `only 1 item can add to cart. The latest "add to cart" will override the previous product in cart.`

```
// Empty cart when user visits a product page
function empty_cart_on_product_page() {
    if (is_product()) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'empty_cart_on_product_page');

// Override previously added product when a new product is added to cart
function override_previous_product_in_cart($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if (!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'override_previous_product_in_cart', 10, 3);

function redirect_to_checkout_after_add_to_cart($url) {
    // Check if the user is adding a product to the cart
    if (isset($_REQUEST['add-to-cart'])) {
        // Redirect to the checkout page
        return wc_get_checkout_url();
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout_after_add_to_cart');
```

Comment: thx for your info. Actually, what i really need is just like what i describe in the question @ WC()->cart->empty_cart; whenever user has visited any product page. Can you edit the codes that's not related to pmpro_hasMembershipLevel? This is mainly due to we are running other plugin as well. Such as top up money into the Wallet and then use for future usage. Hence, the cart must be empty whenever user trying to buy the membership or top up money.

Comment: here is the error msg. https://ibb.co/rHdwRqM

Comment: let me explain more in details. For example I have 4 products in Woocomerece now 1. bronze 2. silver 3. gold 4. topup_wallet (another plugin) We didn't display them like a shop. Instead,  we do this   add_to_cart id=PRODUCT_ID . The cart page won't show to user.  If user click Join Bronze, it will link to checkout. But if he change mind and want Silver, the problem will come out. Only 1 membership can add to cart one time.

Comment: Thx for your update. But after adding your codes, when user click add to cart, it remain on the same product page without linking to checkout. The cart is empty too.  The flow should be like this 

user visit product page-> clear cart -> Add to cart -> checkout...

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Can you remove my code? I want to check the flow of your site.

Comment: ok, just removed it

Comment: Thx for your update2, it redirect user to checkout directly from product page 1 after clicking add to cart. However, if the user didn't finished the checkout and back to previous page, and then visit product page 2, then the problem will come out @ You may only add one membership to your cart.  That's why the cart need to be cleared whenever user visit the product page, then Add to cart -> checkout .

Comment: maybe to put it this way, we ignore the normal cart function. only 1 item can add to cart. The latest "add to cart" will override the previous product in cart. 

1. user visit any product page, the 1st thing is WC()->cart->empty_cart(); 
2. now the cart is empty, user add to cart will be the current product, hence the cart won't have 2 or more products.
3. checkout